What are the issues with absolute risk reduction/relative risk reduction vs odds ratios in reference to variation over risk factors
The following quote is from this:
Any measure that has the potential for summarizing a treatment effect with one constant for all types of patients will be non-collapsible when the outcome is categorical or represents time to event. Collapsible measures such as absolute risk reduction and relative risk reduction must vary over risk factors (creating mathematical but not subject-matter-relevant interactions), otherwise probabilities will arise that are outside the allowable range of [0,1].
I have a few questions about it.

The first two sentence seem contradictory. Count data is categorical, but can produce collapsible summary statistics?
I don't understand why the second sentence is true. Don't we calculate the probabilities first, then the ARR and RRR?
Given they do vary and lead to probabilities outside the range [0,1], does this have implications for using a Poisson, or any other regression that estimates risk ratios?


For 1 you have to be clear on the summary measure being used, e.g., a ratio vs. a difference in counts.
For 2 think about which probabilities are well-defined and relevant.  When there are covariates/risk factors each probability is conditional on the values of these factors.  If instead you want to refer to collapsible absolute risk reductions, this pertains to the ill-defined case where you summarize disparate risks with a marginal average, stratified only by (say) treatment.  For sample averaged treatment effects you don’t need individualized probability estimates until you compute the variance of the marginal estimates.
Logistic and Poisson models will result in legal probability estimates under all situations.  Whether the models provide a good fit is another matter.  What can result in illegal probabilities is a model that does not put restrictions on the estimated values, e.g., additive linear models.

Thanks for replying. I'm not sure I follow your response for 2; why do collapsible ARRs not applying to disparate risks lead to probabilities outside the [0,1] range? Also, I didn't know there are collapsible and non collapsible ARRs; what are these and are there RR and RRR analogues?

What is "collapsible absolute risk reductions" please ?

If you estimate an ARR that is not covariate specific, that ARR averages over a variety of individual risk profiles. If you try to apply the ARR out of context, e.g., used a marginal ARR to apply to a low risk person, subtracting the margin ARR from the low risk may result in a negative risk.  And to my knowledge ARRs based on crude marginal estimates are always collapsible, and this doesn’t matter for fully conditional (covariate adjusted) ARRs.  So the main distinction to be made is conditional vs. marginal estimates.
